# How to check "Is Nothing" in Linq dynamic query

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to check a very basic expression with Linq dynamic queries.
Although this woks perfectly with regular Linq.

```
  Dim xxx = From x In db.Users Where x.AgentID Is Nothing Select x.FirstName, x.LastName
```

it seems not to work with dynamic queries:

```
Dim xx = db.Users.Where("AgentID Is Nothing").ToList
```

I get this error:

> Boolean expression expected

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You must have a Boolean expression not a string to get the result like:
    Dim xx = db.Users.Where(u=>u.AgentID==null).ToList()

Comment: Thank U very much for your help, but my question was related to DynamicLinq which is precisely the way of using strings in this place. It works very well as long the expression is obviousely boolean "IsAgent = True" or "FirstName.Contains('Pau')".

Answer (score 0):

I found following solution :

```
"AgentID.HasValue = False"
```